# ctrl+tab functinality in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

If you press ctrl+tab in the .NET IDE, it shows all the active files and their images. Can anybody tell me how to implement this functionally using WPF?

Comment: Did you try to do it? Try it and ask when you get stuck on something specific. If you did try it, what did you fail on?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to use a [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) control and probably a custom control that can show an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28VS.95%29.aspx) alongside some text (probably use a [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label%28VS.95%29.aspx) or [`TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx)). You can then enumerate your open files and create one control for each, placing it into the columns and rows of the [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx).

Give it a try and tell us how you get on. It would be great to see you post back with your solution or a link to your solution. Good luck!